# What abstract things can you 吸收？

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

So, I recently learned 吸收 can be used abstractly. Looking around example sentences we have

- 吸收知识
- 吸收A的思想
- 吸收B的信念
- 吸收A的经验

Two questions: 
 1. How common are these collocations? How colloquial? 
 2. Could these collocations be used in an active way? For example

```
我去台湾的原因是吸收知识。
```

or

```
这个暑假在脸书实习我计划尽量吸收这个公司的知识。
```

Thanks for the guidance guys!

Comment: I would say only 吸收知识 is common, but none are colloquial. Your examples are understandable but sound funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gao Weiwei mentioned, only 吸收知识 is common.  `吸收 - to absorb`:

```
吸收知识 = Absorbing knowledge
```

(yea why not!)

```
吸收A的思想  = Absorbing A's mind / ideas / thought
```

(think we should use 'accept' instead of 'absorb'?)

```
吸收 B的信念 = Absorbing B's belief
```

(same as above)

```
吸收 A 的经验 = Absorbing A's experience
```

(While 吸收经验 is actually a common phase; 吸收 someone's 经验 isn't, basically we `gain` experience instead of absorbing someone's experience, which sounds like you're eating their brain..)

Comment: Or you can say 吸取他人的经验, meaning *to learn from others' experience*.

Comment: ^ yes thanks Weiwei, another usage that involves another person's experience

Answer (score 3):

Basically anything that can be absorbed as nutrients, literally or figuratively. Yours are just a few examples, we can have more!

A plant may absorb the essence of the nature, or `吸收日月精华`, and become a genie.

A political party may want to attract and invite the best people to join. Mao Zedong wanted more learned people in CCP, so he wrote 《[大量吸收知识分子](https://www.marxists.org/chinese/maozedong/marxist.org-chinese-mao-19391201.htm)》. Now CCP is still trying to 吸收入党积极分子 in colleges, companies, and danweis.

Search 吸收 for book titles and you get plenty:

- 有吸收力的心灵 A spongy heart?
- 清末民初民間儒教對主流儒學的吸收與轉化 Absorption of mainstream Confucianism
- 早期天台学对唯识古学的吸收与抉择 Absorption of certain academic topic
- 三十天吸收三十年專業能力 Absorption of certain abilities
- 人力资源吸收与选拔 Absorption of human resources
- 技术吸收型对外贸易战略研究 Absorption of technology
- 中国吸收外资30年 Absorption of capital investment
- 知识的吸收与创造 Absorption of knowledge

A company may completely buy off another and it's called [吸收合并](http://baike.baidu.com/view/3925746.htm), in which case the company being bought is likely to be dissolved and will no longer function as an entity.

There is a criminal offense called "[非法吸收公众存款罪](http://www.xyzlove.com/Noun/ffxsgzckz.htm)". You illegally collect people's money and do your secret stuff.

---

I don't think I'm finished, but let's just stop for a while. Your two examples are not colloquial because, well, you wouldn't say these in English, would you:

> I come to Taiwan to absorb knowledge.
>
> I joined Facebook as a summer intern to absorb their knowledge.

Same reason, if it's personal, and if it's casual talk, the word `absorb` or `吸收` will sound too fancy. You usually say `to learn` or `to study` in such occasions.

Contrary to @Alex's opinion on `思想`. `思想` can also be `吸收`-ed. `吸收` is an active activity<sup>1</sup>. You would need to provide the specific topic for `吸收` though, as in `吸收儒家思想`. On the other hand, I can't think of any example in which `信念` is `吸收`-ed.

These are just my opinions. Have I mentioned that opinions can also be absorbed? 也许吸收了我和别人的意见以后，你会形成一个更完整的看法。

<sub>1. Sorry, running out of vocabs.</sub>

Comment: I think people normally say plants `吸收养分` rather than `吸收日月精华`, which is a phrase one often finds in `(武侠)小说`. Google did find some instances of the usage of `吸收信念`, e.g. `思想传染，研究的不是一般人如何吸收信念`, but IMO this style of writing is not good because one would want to avoid using abstract words if possible. Your writing is very good, especially the last paragraph.